# Reference request: Fuchsian Model of compact Riemann surface

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $S$ be a compact Riemann surface with genus $\geq$ 2. Then by the Uniformization theorem it has universal covering space the upper half-plane $\mathbb{H}$(up to conformal equivalence). Now I read that we can express $S$ as $\mathbb{H}/\Gamma$, where $\Gamma$ is a stricly hyperbolic Fuchsian group. The statement sounds reasonable, but I want to have a actual proof of that. Can someone suggest a reference for that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is proved in Benedetti and Petronio's book *Lectures on Hyperbolic Geometry* in proposition B.1.6.

Comment: @CamiloArosemena-Serrato That one helps a lot. Thank you very much.

Comment: @CamiloArosemena-Serrato In my copy of Benedetti and Petronio's book, Proposition B.1.6 is a characterization of properly discontinuous free actions on locally compact spaces. Are we looking at the same version of the book?